# fgetcsv - Perform function on first column value?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have a csv with two rows.

```
if (($handle = fopen("twoRows.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
print_r($data);
```

This returns two arrays with a line break at the end of the first array.

If I want to access the first column, I do

```
echo $data[0];
```

And get

```
value1
value2
```

Yet, if I do something like:

```
$data[0] = $post_ID;
echo 'Post ID = ' . $post_ID . '<br />';
```

I get zero output on $post_ID

```
Post ID =
Post ID =
```

How can I perform a function on each first column value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where is `$post_ID` declared?

Don't you mean to do

```
$post_ID = $data[0];

echo 'Post ID = ' . $post_ID . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `$data[0]` to `$post_ID`, it should be the other way around:

```
$post_ID = $data[0];
echo 'Post ID = ' . $post_ID . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it inside your loop:

```
if (($handle = fopen("twoRows.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $post_ID = $data[0];
        echo 'Post ID = ' . $post_ID . '<br />';
    }
}
```